# IOS safari or Chrome read / write file via USB

Tags: javascript, ios

Does IOS Safari / Chrome browser allows accessing file from USB device / Stick connected via USB (Lighting to USB adapter)? I did a quick google and seems like uploading (write) is not possible but maybe read is possible?

According to this https://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem
Seems like IOS Safari does not support file system / file writer api

But it supports File api
https://caniuse.com/#search=file%20api

Any comments would be highly appreciated.

Comment: JavaScript does not write to the Client's Computer, including drives (unless the System allows it, like Raspberry Pi). You can read a file that has been uploaded, with permission from the Client, even from a USB Storage device.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that the file cannot be written to the client's computer but it is possible to create the file blob and provide the download link for the client to download with javascript. However not with the case of IOS system. 

Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS, File API connected to 'Files' application which provides connection to several cloud services and access permission to internal shared storage.

Currently, 'Files' application doesn't support file access to external devices.
If you want to access to external devices with File API, you must use 3rd party application which supports 'Files' application as a pipe.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense

Comment: In addition to my question. Can I read & write the file to the device's internal shared storage?

Comment: @RobertChan File API is 'File read API', therefore you only can read from internal shared storage. There is no difference between Safari and Chrome. Be care, the browser doesn't have an internal shared storage area for itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Much appreciated